# Há uma forma de se conectar a um servidor socket hospedado como localhost pelo CMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, internet

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de executar meu servidor em socket python e me conectar a ele utilizando o prompt de comando. Há algum meio de se fazer isso?

Comment: Se você não for trabalhar com informações binárias, pode utilizar o "comando" telnet: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet%20%22Telnet. Porem, nas novas versões do Windows, esse comando deve ser habilitado.

Comment: Sim. Mas o que você quer fazer? Conectar a partir de outro programa Ptyhon? Ou de algum programa específico?